# Error trying to upgrade Oracle 11g to 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I downloaded Oracle 12.c and selected the option to upgrade my current database.
At 86 % I got the error on the image : 
Database Upgrade Checks -> Upgrade Storage Checks. 
What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the settings for the SYSTEM tablespace and datafiles?  Run this query to get some details:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLESPACE', 'SYSTEM') from dual;
```

My guess is that the SYSTEM tablespace is set to a small maxsize.  This command may fix the problem:

```
alter database datafile 'E:\ORACLE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF' 
  autoextend on maxsize unlimited;
```

The path contains "XE", are you using Express Edition?  I wouldn't be surprised if it was impossible to upgrade Express Edition to 12c.  Express Edition contains some artificial limitations and is neither patched nor (seriously) supported.